# Golang Checking file extension not working

Tags: file, go

I want to get a file path from the console and check if the file is a vm file.
I wrote this code:

```
func main() {
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Println("Enter the path of the vm file:")
path, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
if filepath.Ext(path) != ".vm" {
    fmt.Println("Error! file must be vm file")
}
```

but it's not working. I just started learn Go So please accept my apologies if this is a basic mistake.

Comment: For a simple use case like this, I think a [bufio.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) is more convenient to use.

Answer (score 21):

For checking file extension:

```golang
path := "/media/godfather.mp4"

fileExtension := filepath.Ext(path)

if fileExtension != ".mp4" {
    panic("File extension ins't equal to .mp4")
}
```

Comment: upvote for godfather (and for helping answer ofc)

Comment: this doesn't work for the composite extensions such as `.tar.gz` (returns `.gz`)

Answer (score 8):

The `path, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')` also returns the newline. So your comparing ".vm\n" with ".vm".

you should trimspace from the path `if filepath.Ext(strings.TrimSpace(path)) != ".vm" {`